# Cherrypy: Can't get my POST data

Tags: python, post, get, cherrypy

I write a tiny webapp with CherryPy. But I has a problem - I can't get my POST data, but GET is ok. Hosted on local host (Win 7), viewed with Opera 10, using CherryPy built-in server.

Here is some code:

```
class Expose:
def __init__(self, fn):
    self.fn = fn

@cherrypy.expose()
def index(self, login=None):
    print 'LOGIN: ' + str(login)
    return self.fn(login=login)

import auth
root.process_form = Expose(auth.process_form)
```

This is is my URL switch. LOGIN prints None if form uses POST, and proper value for GET. Here is my form (template):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
<p>Create new user</p>

<form action="/process_form" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="login" value="login" />
  <input type="text" name="email" value="me@company.com" />
  <input type="text" name="password" value="123" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>
```

I can't guess what goes wrong. What may I check?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
<p>Create new user</p>

<form action="/process_form/" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="login" value="login" />
  <input type="text" name="email" value="me@company.com" />
  <input type="text" name="password" value="123" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>
```

Note the final slash in "/process_form/

Comment: Thank you! Exatly! CherryPy with my server settings generated redirect if final slash omitted and lost POST data. I tuned server settings, but it's good practice to finish url with / I think.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if root.processform is something special in CherryPy, if not you need to expose a process_form page

```
@cherrypy.expose()
def process_form(self, email, login,password):
    ...stuff...
```

I may be missing something